# Android failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10064: Read-only file system in emulator

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

### I am trying to run a video stored locally in android

- I am able to play the video on the actual device.
- I am not able to run it on the android simulator.

***The Video is not playing, I am getting the error below***

```
failed to make and chown /acct/uid_10064: Read-only file system
```

How will I resolve this? Are there any settings that I need to change on the android simulator?

Comment: which android version. which video play software? if this is your own implementation of a player do other players work on the emulator?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this by deleting the simulator(emulator) and then recreating it.

Comment: As for me I shutted down emulator completely and launched it again. Now error is gone

Answer (score 1):

1. Add path (sdk\platform-tools) into your environment values（D:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools).
2. Enter into "cmd"

> ```
> #adb shell
> #su
> #chmod 777 /data  (change the folder data to rwx)
> ```

3. Enjoy yourself. You change other folder.